# Measuring ITLB_FLUSH on icelake processors

Tags: x86, cpu, perf, tlb, intel-pmu

According to the Intel website for performance counters at https://perfmon-events.intel.com/, there are counters specifically for ITLB.ITLB_FLUSH for processors based on the "skylake" microarchitecture (e.g. Skylake client, Cascade Lake-X server).
However, there are no counters for ITLB_FLUSH in icelake client or icelake server processors. What's recommended way to measure ITLB flush events on these processors?